# Cannot resolve symbol 'support' (using Android Studio, following getting started guide)

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I am getting started with Android development.
I have followed this [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity) guide and use **Android Studio** (not eclipse).

I ran Hello World on my device, so far so good.  But..

Problem starts when adding this import: (as instructed by the guide)

```
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;  // cannot resolve symbol 'support'
```

Seems its needed by this line (commenting it and auto-resolving the import didnt work)

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

The support import is red underlined, mouseover tells me `Cannot resolve symbol 'support'`

Build wont work either ofcourse. I have seen answers to similar questions such as; 
suggesting clearing cache and retarting (tried that),
suggesting running SDK Manager as Administrator and updating (tried that),
and some other problems/solutions that seem eclipse specific.

I am new to Android development and the IDE. How about fixing this in Android Studio v0.2.9 ?

**Edit:**

Contents of my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {

    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

Comment: First I would suggest updating to the most recent version (0.3.1). Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Do you have the support library installed? Can you post you build.gradle file?

Comment: Please post your build.gradle and check if you have installed the support library from the SDK Manager.

Comment: @redGREENblue i added the build.gradle file contents.

Comment: Seems i cant edit the comment so..

@fasteque i added the build.gradle file contents, and i have the `Extras/Android Support Library` installed in SDK Manager. (and updated)

@Adam-Johns Is the Early Access Program stable enough for production development? I cant afford losing time on IDE bugs or corrupted project files. I am on the Milestone Releases (fka Dev Channel ?) right now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modify your gradle file like below and try if it works.

```
......

    dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'

        // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
        // The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
        // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem. 

Just uncommenting the v7 line resulted in problems with `R.`. Can you tell me why this works and that doesnt? What does the v7 mean, is it a version number? Why does the gradle file mention v7 instead of v4?

Is this a problem that occurs more often when using import? Or is it by design even? How can i throubleshoot this myself in the future?

Comment: They are both different support libraries with different feature support. V4 for API level 4+ and V7 for Api level 7+. I suggest you go through this link for more details  http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Comment: I have since had IDE warnings about `R.string.foobar` that i did properly define in `strings_foobar.xml`, build worked OK though. After i upgraded to the latest Android Studio (0.3.1 via Early Access Preview) a cache-rebuild and restart fixed that.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but i cant seem to find this `build.gradle` file, i am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1

Comment: I made this align with my buildToolsVersion - seemed like a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

Fix in Android Studio using the GUI, without the direct editing of the Gradle files (*validated for Android Studio starting v1.0.1 to v2.2.3*):

1. Right-click your module in the project tree. It is one, in most cases the first, of the root nodes. By default, it is called `app`.
2. In the menu choose *Open Module Settings*:

   [image]
3. Switch to *Dependencies* tab.
4. Click the add button (+) at the bottom of the dialog window.
5. Choose *Library Dependency*.
6. Choose `support-v4` from the list.
7. Click *OK* and rebuild.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of editing the `build.gradle` I did it the maven way with right mouse on your root project -> Open Module Settings -> Dependencies Tab -> + -> Maven Dependency -> Search For "NavUtils" and select `com.google.android:support-v4:r7@jar`.

SDK Version 19 and Android Studio 0.4.2

Comment: Also, in the SDK Manager you need to have installed these two: "Android Support Repository" and "Android Support Library" (they are under the "Extras" category)